# NavigationComponent navigate away from BottomNavitationView

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using NavitationComponent and my start screen has a `BottomNavigationView`. This is declared in my activity's XML, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Screen contents -->
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/home_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to navigate to a separate screen entirely, that does not feature the BottomNavigationView. However since it lives on the Activity it persists. What is the recommended approach in such case? I would like to avoid using `startActivity`, that just feels like defeating the purpose of having Navigation Component in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using BottomNavigation with Android Navigation Component in an enterprise app we face multiple issues:

1. Handling back stack in conjunction with BottomNavigation that has a workaround inside Google Samples.
2. Using a shared Toolbar with a dynamic menu updates
3. Android BottomNavigation hide/show in different fragments

We ended up with this solution:

In our Activity we set a listener for the navigation component:

```
findNavController().addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
```

```
override fun onDestinationChanged(controller: NavController, destination: NavDestination, arguments: Bundle?) {
        //Check Destination
}
```

We defined UI configs (Toolbar & BottomNavigation) for each fragment:

```
data class UiConfig(val toolbarConfig: ToolbarConfig, val bottomNavigationConfig: BottomNavigationConfig)

data class ToolbarConfig(val showToolbar: Boolean, val title: String, val menu: Int)

data class BottomNavigationConfig(val showBottomNavigation: Boolean)

object UIConfigs {

    val uiConfigs = mapOf(
            R.id.fragment_id to UiConfig(ToolbarConfig(true, "Title", R.menu.home), BottomNavigationConfig(false)),
            ...
    )

}
```

And in our listener when destination changed (`onDestinationChanged`):

```
when (destination.id) {
    R.id.fragment_id -> {
        //Update UI by accessing uiConfigs and getting the info about fragment
       //hide/show BottomNavigation
      //update your shared Toolbar
      //Any shared updates in possible this way
    }
    else -> throw Exception("No config found for ${destination.label}")
}
```

Comment: I see. So essentially you have a single activity with an XML with both toolbar and bottom navigation widgets, that you hide or show depending on which fragment you get a callback for under `onDestinationChanged` . That's an ingenious solution, and answers my question that apparently there isn't yet a way to achieve this just by what the components offer currently. Thank you

Comment: @pedronveloso AndroidNavigation offers lots of pros and cons at the same time. I still believe in the old Multi-Activity Multi-Fragment approach. I also voted your question up. great to see some challenging ones ;)